# How many bits of information are possible in an eight-character password if any character can be used?

Tags: security, math, operating-system

In this question, do we assume that each character is just 8 bits then? In this case, is the answer just 64 bits? Sorry if this is a dumb question.

Comment: It's your question, you make the assumptions. Just be sure to add them to the question.

Answer (score 0):

*Any* character would be hard to use in a password as some of those are [not even printable](https://web.itu.edu.tr/sgunduz/courses/mikroisl/ascii.html) (like a \07 beep). But if you assume that it really can be any (so it's more like a cryptographically random key than a password), then yes, 64 bits of entropy.

If it's case sensitive ascii letters (26+26) and numbers (10), and the length is 8, and it's all true random, then it's more like log2( (26+26+10)^8 ) ~= 47.6 bits.

Or more generally, using k different random characters for a length of n, the entropy would be log2(k^n).